# Elasticsearch parse date field in different format

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I create an index in ES7.8 with date format "yyyy-MM-dd"

```
"mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "BaseLine": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
        },
```

However, when I click the "Baseline" field on the map, the actual value passed on Filter is yyyy-MM-dd00:00:00.000Z.

Can anyone advise how can I get the correct date format "yyyy-MM-dd" in the filter?

Thanks.

[image]

Here is the sample document from a request

> "hits" : [
> {
> "_index" : "program_b",
> "_type" : "_doc",
> "_id" : "2137SD19.1",
> "_score" : 0.0,
> "_source" : {
> "SiteID" : 2137,
> "BaseLine" : "2020-04-26",
> "uk" : "2137SD19.1"
> }
> },

Comment: Can you show a sample document that you have indexed. Ideally the one you clicked on on the map

Comment: @Val I have edited the post with a response in Dev tool. Hope that works. The original documents are in .csv format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The role of the `"format": "yyyy-MM-dd"` in your mapping is only to tell ES in which format your date values will be present in your source document.

As you can see, your source document contains `"BaseLine" : "2020-04-26"` which is exactly in the format that you've instructed ES to expect. When you index your document, ES will properly parse your `BaseLine` date field and index a long value representing that point in time.

The value you see in the tooltip (i.e. `Apr 26, 2020`) is just how Kibana formats your dates, you can change that in "Stack Management > Advanced settings" if needed.

Finally, the filter value you see in your filter (i.e. `2020-04-26T00:00:00.000Z`) is the ISO8601 representation of your `BaseLine` field and what ES use in the query filter.

Everything looks perfectly correct as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. But the problem is when I click the "Baseline" filed from the map, the Timelion Chart of the same Dashboard will report this error: [parse_exception] failed to parse date field [2020-04-26T00:00:00.000Z] with format [yyyy-MM-dd]: [failed to parse date field [2020-04-26T00:00:00.000Z] with format [yyyy-MM-dd]]

Comment: Well, you didn't mention Timelion in your initial question :-) Can you tell a bit more how your Timelion expression looks like?

Comment: What you can do, is to change the format to `date_optional_time` instead of `yyyy-MM-dd` so both `2020-04-26` and `2020-04-26T00:00:00.000Z` would be allowed

Comment: Yes, the error is gone after I change the format to "date_optional_time". Thanks, headps~